# Function returns 1/2 of the array that's passed to it

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My function is returning 1/2 of the array that I pass to it.

When I process this array:

```
$output2 = 
Array
(
[sel_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[repair_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 1
    )

)
```

Using

```
foreach($output2 as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
            echo "$key - $value2<br />";
            $new[$key][] = $value2;
        }
    }

}
```

It returns the array in the original (desired) format:

```
Array
(
[sel_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[repair_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 1
    )

)
```

But when I pass it through my function to clean the values:

```
function cleanValues2($array){
    foreach($array as $key1 => $value1){
        if(is_array($value1)){
            foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
                $trm = trim($value2);
                $strp = strip_tags($trm);
                $fltr1 = filter_var($strp,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $fltr2 = filter_var($fltr1,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
                $fltr3 = htmlspecialchars($fltr2);
                $strtoup = strtoupper($fltr3);
                $new_array[$key1][] = $strtoup;
            }
            return $new_array;
        }
    }
}
```

It returns half of the array:

```
Array
(
[sel_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added return statement in the forloop due to which only first array value is getting iterated.

Place this return after the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I hate it when I waste hours on simple mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

Move the return outside the outer foreach loop.

```
function cleanValues2($array){
        foreach($array as $key1 => $value1){
            if(is_array($value1)){
                foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
                    $trm = trim($value2);
                    $strp = strip_tags($trm);
                    $fltr1 = filter_var($strp,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $fltr2 = filter_var($fltr1,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
                    $fltr3 = htmlspecialchars($fltr2);
                    $strtoup = strtoupper($fltr3);
                    $new_array[$key1][] = $strtoup;
                }

            }
        }
        return $new_array;
    }
```